# Let $G$ be a group of order $n$. Prove that $G$ has at most $n$ different cyclic subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $n$. Prove that $G$ has at most $n$ different cyclic subgroups.

I know that the generators from the group form the cyclic subgroup. The number of generators, at most, is the number of elements from the group, ($n$). How to go about proving this?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the argument is *"Any cyclic subgroup is generated by* ***at least one*** *element; therefore there can't be any* ***more*** *cyclic subgroups than there are elements of $G$."*

To be more formal, let $X$ be the set of cyclic subgroups of $G$, i.e.,
$$X=\{H\subseteq G:H = \langle g\rangle \text{ for some }g\in G\}$$
Let $f:G\to X$ be the function that takes an element $g\in G$, and outputs $\langle g\rangle\in X$, the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by that element $g$. In symbols, this would be written $f(g)=\langle g\rangle$.

Any cyclic subgroup $H$ of $G$ is in fact generated by some element of $G$ (by definition). That is, any element of $X$ equals $f(g)$ for some $g\in G$. This simply says that $f:G\to X$ is surjective, and therefore the cardinality of $X$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $G$.

Note that $f$ is usually **not** injective; that is, many elements will generate the same cyclic subgroup. For example, in $G=\mathbb{Z}_{6}$, we have the cyclic subgroups
$$X=\{\{0\},\{0,3\},\{0,2,4\},\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\}$$
and the function $f:G\to X$ acts like this:
$$\begin{align*}
f(0)=\langle 0\rangle &= \{0\}\\
f(1)=\langle 1\rangle &= \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\\
f(2)=\langle 2\rangle &= \{0,2,4\}\\
f(3)=\langle 3\rangle &= \{0,3\}\\
f(4)=\langle 4\rangle &= \{0,2,4\}\\
f(5)=\langle 5\rangle &= \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Telling a cyclic group is equivalent to telling a generator of it; since $G$ has order $n$, the $n$ elements will give at most $n$ cyclic groups.